# How to update global header and footer

Tags: switch-to-blog

I have a problem with the global header and footer in multisite. When I change the root's header and footer, the subsites (all other blogs) don't update.

This is my code:

```
global $switched;
switch_to_blog(1);
get_header();
restore_current_blog();

switch_to_blog(1);
get_footer();
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: [Resolve]
i'm using this code !
`<?php
global $switched;
switch_to_blog(1);
//get_footer();
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include ($root.'/wp-content/themes/themename/footer.php');
restore_current_blog();
?>`

Comment: You should post this as an answer, instead of a comment or edit. It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and you can even choose to accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using this code:

```
global $switched; 
switch_to_blog(1); 
//get_header(); 
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); 
include ($root.'/wp-content/themes/themename/header.php'); 
restore_current_blog();

global $switched;
switch_to_blog(1); 
//get_footer(); 
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); 
include ($root.'/wp-content/themes/themename/footer.php'); 
restore_current_blog();
```